# How to start session at simpleID server without submitting the form

Tags: php, curl, openid, owncloud

I am going to integrate simpleID(openId server) with the ownCloud(open
source private cloud). Here I want to login to both ownCloud and
simpleID only once. I mean, when I login to ownCloud using my user
name and password, then I should be logged into simpleID also without
asking further login form from simpleID server.

For that after I logged into ownCloud, I used PHP curl code and sent
parameters like `'name=myname'`, `'pass=123'` and `'q=login'` (Those are
parameters I think it should send to simpleID server). Here is my curl
code.

```
<?php

$h = curl_init();

curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/simpleid/www/index.php");
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'q' => 'login',
'name' => 'myname',
'pass' => '123'
));
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($h);
echo 'dd : '.$result;

?>
```

But I can't start session successfully in the simpleID server. Please
tell me what are the all parameters I should send to the server or how
I should start a session in simpleID without submitting a form.

I like to give **100** bounty for a helpful answer.

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: did u solve it? i also need help

Answer (score 0):

If the simpleID server is running on the same domainname then you need to supply the sessionid in the curl call. But if the goal is to have a openID server, there is an owncloud app that does this. See the user_openid_provider app